# ERROR: MicroBatchExecution while trying to stream a basic PySpark Application

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm just trying to run this basic streaming PySpark Application

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkStream').getOrCreate()
lines = (spark.readStream.format('socket').option('host','localhost').option('port',9999).load())
words = lines.select(split(col('value'),'\\s').alias('word'))
counts = words.groupBy('word').count()
checkpt = 'C:/checkpoint/'
streamingQuery = (counts.writeStream.format('console').outputMode('complete').trigger(processingTime='1 second').option('checkpointLocation', checkpt).start())
streamingQuery.awaitTermination()
```

I'm getting this error with this code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooF3S.png)

I was expecting that it should run and i can able to stream my Inputs on the output window.

Comment: Can you verify that you have hadoop's `bin` directory in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Yes, it's path is already added in the environment variable @KarimElawaad